# How to use spaces and angle brackets for TARGET in .pro file

Tags: c++, qt

I want to name my Qt application as

> test <2>

So I write my .pro file as

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test\\\ \\\<2\\\>

QT = core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES +=  main.cpp
```

But it fails when building:

```
11:14:31: Running steps for project asdf...
11:14:31: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:14:31: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/home/erik/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake -o Makefile ../asdf/asdf.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
WARNING: DESTDIR: Cannot access directory '../build-asdf-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/test/ /<2'
/bin/sh: 1: cannot open 2/: No such file
/bin/sh: 1: cannot open 2/: No such file
Makefile:254: recipe for target 'test/ //<2/>' failed
make: *** [test/ //<2/>] Error 2
11:14:31: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project asdf (kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
11:14:31: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

How should I escape the characters in TARGET?

Comment: My question is: why?

Comment: In the official tutorial of Qt https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners#A_pretty_button an application is named as test <2>, so I wonder how they can do this.

Comment: that is the title of the window, not the name of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't, and in case of qmake: you can't, since the resulting makefiles will be unusable. Most operating systems reserve those characters, and while a file with such a name may be representable in the filesystem - it can't be used in typical ways. See e.g. [Filename:Reserved characters and words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) for an overview.

The titles of application windows (e.g. as seen [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners#A_pretty_button)) have nothing to do with file names. You can set them to whatever you want using `QWidget`'s `windowTitle` property.